# send email notification to contract owner 30 days before the contract end date

Tags: contracts

I have a requirement where i need to send an email notification to the contract owner 30 days before the contract end date , when the contract role is 'SA/EB?TA' etc.Any suggestion  with an example very much appreciated.

Comment: You can write a time based **Workflow Rule** which has the criteria that **contract role is 'SA/EB?TA'**.

Comment: @Ruchi:Thanks for your response.But the workflow will get fired once when the criteria is met nd used for single record and if their are n of contracts having the expiry dates then the alert need to be send .So looking forward for any alternative like trigger or batch classes.

Comment: Do you want to send email continuously every day?

Comment: @KiranMachhewar:Not every day ,but the first email will be sent before 30 days of contract end date and next email needs to be sent  15 days before the contract end date to the users and superior.Any suggestion please.

Comment: You can have multiple time trigger actions in that case.